# new line in JS-function

Tags: javascript, line, newline, break

I would like to get a longer string with line breaks, but it's not working with all the common commands like `\n, \r\n`, ... Also not with HTML-Tags for breaking a line.
I am new to the ASP-Framework and JS-Scripting and I can't find the solution on my own. Till now I didn't find the right hint on the internet, you can help me when you have a look at my specific code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>DataGen App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <h3>Mitarbeiter</h3>   
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="generateSQL" onclick="generate();" />
    <p id="ma" />
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var uri = 'api/mitarbeiter';

      function formatItem(item) {
          return 'INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter VALUES (' + item.Id + ', ' + item.Name + ', ' + item.Vorname + ', ' + item.Bereich + ');';
      }

      function generate() {
          var str = "";
          $.getJSON(uri)
              .done(function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                      str = str + "\n" + formatItem(item);
                      $('#ma').text(str);
                  });
              })
      }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The line break should be generated in the last function.

Thank's a lot and have a nice week!

Comment: jquery 2.0.3 is outdated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/ajax/cdn/overview#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0

Comment: to the newline issue: you have to use `<br>` tags. just so you know: `.text()` will convert it to plain text. if you want to throw some html in there you'd have to either change `.text` to `.html` or do more advanced stuff. just so you know: if you use `.html` you should probably filter `formatItem` to prevent possible xss

Comment: Hey, thank you very much. To convert into html text was helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<br>` tag. The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>DataGen App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <h3>Mitarbeiter</h3>   
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="generateSQL" onclick="generate();" />
    <p id="ma" />
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      var uri = 'api/mitarbeiter';

      function formatItem(item) {
          return 'INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter VALUES (' + item.Id + ', ' + item.Name + ', ' + item.Vorname + ', ' + item.Bereich + ');';
      }

      function generate() {
          var str = "";
          $.getJSON(uri)
              .done(function (data) {
              console.log(data);
                  $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                      str = str + "<br>" + formatItem(item);
                      $('#ma').html(str);
                  });
              })
      }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```